# Generating function from recursion with division by index $n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I've got stuck in my homework, and I don't really know if I should look for another solution or I just don't have enough knowledge to do it. So I need to find generating function (as in title) for:
$$ b_{n+1} = b_{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}b_{n}, b_0 = 2 $$
And I get to the point:
$$ B(x) = xB(x) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{n}b_{n-1}x^n) + 2 $$
And now I'm stuck. I know the sum above is integral of B(x), but is it possible to get something more of it, maybe by convolution? I would be grateful for some hint, or just tip that it is impossible to get compact form of it.

//Edited typo, sorry.

Comment: Is there a typo in your recursion formula?  As it stands, there is no way to calculate $b_1$.

Comment: $b_{n+1} = b_{n} + \frac{1}{n}b_{n}$ - is it right?

Comment: Sorry, I had typo.

Comment: It is easy to solve this type of recurrence relation. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Rsolve%28+%7B+b%5Bn%2B1%5D%3Db%5Bn%5D%2Bb%5Bn%5D%2F%28n%2B1%29+%29) is what you should get.

Comment: I just had to overcomplicate it and get stuck... Thanks for help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear first order recurrence. If you have:
$$
x_{n + 1} - a_n x_n = f_n
$$
you can divide by $a_n a_{n - 1} \ldots a_0$ and get a new recurrence in $\dfrac{x_n}{a_{n - 1} a_{n - 2} \ldots a_0}$ with a left hand side that telescopes nicely, and a simple sum at the right.